# Where to put business logic that requires the current_user to be known? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model (say `Car`) in which a method needs access to the current_user to determine if the user is allowed to perform the things that the method does.

For example, a method might want to do these things:

1. Check that current_user owns this object
2. Check that the object status == 1 (Active)
3. Check that a related object exists and it's X field is not NULL

I need this business logic to be in the *model*, *not in the controller*, so that it's the *one place* where my business logic will be. The method might get called from places other than a controller.

I know that there are gems like cancan, declarative_authorization etc. but they seem to be overkill for what I need to do. And also, accessing current_user in a model is not considered the "right way".

Then, how do I make that check in the model but still feel "clean"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced a situation where "current_user" needs be tightly connected to a model, but I handled it all in the Controller and it works pretty well. Here are some examples:

My model is "Photos". Photos are owned by users, and how people interact with photos is obviously tightly related to whether or not they own the photo.

In the show action I need to load either the existing rating a user has given to a photo (so they can edit it) or allow them to create a new one:

```
def show
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  if user_signed_in?      
    if @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_photo_id(params[:id])
      @rating
      @current_user_rating = @rating.value
    else
      @rating = current_user.ratings.new
      @current_user_rating = "n/a"
    end
  end
end
```

When people create photos I want them to be automatically assigned to the current user.

```
def new
  @photo = Photo.new
end

def create
  @photo = current_user.photos.create(params[:photo])
  if @photo.save
    redirect_to user_path(current_user), :notice => t('photo.notice.created')
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Only the owners of a photo can change them:

```
def edit
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  if @photo.user == current_user
    render 'edit'
  else
    redirect_to user_path(current_user), :alert => t('application.error.unauthorized')
  end
end

def update
  @photo = current_user.photos.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
  if @photo.save
    redirect_to user_path(current_user), :notice => t('photo.notice.updated')
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

This approach is based on the constraints that a "current_user" object is tied to the session, which only the controller knows about. So, in short, I have yet to find a good way to integrate "current_user" into a model, but I've been able to find (I think) pretty clean ways to tie the model and controller together so that this can be provided by the controller.

One fairly simple solution to most problems, if your controller is starting to get messy, would be to take a chunk of logic and define as a method in the model, but require one argument = a user object. Then you can just feed "current_user" to that method from your controller and the model handles the rest.

Good luck! Also, if anyone else has any better ideas for this, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate it. Your code will likely work, but it does seem kind of wrong to put that in the controller (my opinion only). I'm thinking of putting ALL of my business logic into a single module/class and then mix it in with the models that need it. This way, I know all the logic is in one place (great), and I don't clutter the model or the controller much. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: There's no reason *not* to group all your logic in one place. As long as you're happy with the outcome, the code works as expected, and it keeps you from wondering "where is that particular bit of code again?", then you're in good shape. However... (see next comment due to character limits)

Comment: The more I've worked with Rails the more I've gotten comfortable with the kind of "flow" that exists in the MVC pattern for web apps. For me, I expect most logic to relate to the data in the database, and so it belongs in the model. The logic that handles sessions and HTTP requests to get stuff out of the models feels right in the controller, and a bit of presentation logic makes sense in the view. The trick is, in these edge cases, things like "current_user" seem like data, but really it's not, it's totally related to the HTTP request. (next comment)

Comment: So, for me at least, once I'm comfortable with whether a particular piece of code is either manipulating data, handling http requests, or presenting information to the user; then it just feels wrong to put it any place other than the model, controller, or view (respectively). The last question is, what will keep your program the most DRY throughout? Putting every kind of logic in one module may do that, but on the other hand it might mean you need to create four view files for one situation, instead of one view + a bit of conditional logic. So, test it both ways, then do whatever *works* best!

Comment: FYI, found this nice article: http://www.shaneharvie.com/2008/01/evolution-of-domain-in-rails-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Handle auth'ing in a Controller.

Example: Putting auth logic in parent ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery

  protected 
    # Returns the currently logged in user or nil if there isn't one
    def current_user
      return unless session[:user_id]
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
    end

    # Make current_user available in templates as a helper
    helper_method :current_user

    # Filter method to enforce a login requirement
    # Apply as a before_filter on any controller you want to protect
    def authenticate
      logged_in? ? true : access_denied
    end

    # Predicate method to test for a logged in user    
    def logged_in?
      current_user.is_a? User
    end

    # Make logged_in? available in templates as a helper
    helper_method :logged_in?

    def access_denied
      redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to continue" and return false
    end
end
```

Now that current_user is an accessor to the logged in user and you can access it in any controller, you can do your authorization logic in the appropriate controller before you do anything with the model.

Your right, though. Models don't care about authorization or who is accessing them.

Comment: This is not what I need - the business logic of my model needs to be in the model and for that business logic, I need to access current_user.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what your trying to do in your model? Generally, models shouldn't know about the current request as this work is done in the controller. But sometimes you really can't help it.

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I've updated the question with what kind of business logic I need to do.